# Keep source ip after iptables nat (port-forwarding)

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, port-forwarding

I apologize for creating one more such question, but I could not find a working solution for it.

I need to configure the reverse-proxy with iptables. For this, I use this solution:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d PROXY_IP --dport 1745 -j DNAT --to-destination REAL_IP:1789    
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d REAL_IP ! -s PROXY_IP -j SNAT --to-source PROXY_IP
```

This works fine, but the destination server sees the proxy server's IP address, not the client's IP address

There are no other rules, all policies in the accept mode.

P.S. - I use google translate and I apologize for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't configure reverse proxy with IPTables, it is a separate software that is setup to run as a reverse proxy.

When doing NAT, the source IP cannot be preserved, that is the whole point of NAT, not to expose the source IP address to destination server.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what software to use for creation of such proxy? I need to proxy the tcp / udp port. In the case of 80/443, I can use Nginx, but what should I use if I need to proxy very different ports and protocols?

Comment: You can use nginx `stream` module to proxy TCP connections. However, with that you cannot see the source IP in destination. HTTP / HTTPS is different because you can add the origin IP to an HTTP header in the proxy, and therefore the information can be preserved. So, only if the protocol you are proxying supports some mechanism of preserving the source IP, you can accomplish what you are looking for.